# Цикл по 1 из измерений в двумерном массиве

Tags: c#

Как пройтись только по 1 столбцу массива ?

```
string[,] spisok = new string[50,5];
for (int i = 0; i < spisok.Length; i++) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Зафиксировать" другое измерение:

```
string[,] spisok = new string[50,5];
int column = 3;
for (int row = 0; row < 50; row++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(spisok[row, column]);
}
```

Обратите внимание, что для многомерных массивов [свойство `Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) возвращает общее количество элементов, получить размерность одного из измерений можно с помощью [метода `GetLength()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Вот как раз искал что то вроде метода GetLength() - спасибо !

Comment: Ну так вопрос надо было получше сформулировать ;)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
string[,] spisok = new string[50,5];
for (int i = 0; i < spisok.Length; i++) {
Console.WriteLine(spisok[0,i])
}
```